# How does Dataflow autoscale and distribute workload?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

After reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51179443/cloud-dataflow-how-does-dataflow-do-parallelism), I still have some questions about how Dataflow/Apache Beam distribute workload. The problem I'm running into can be demonstrated with the following code:

```java
package debug;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner;
import org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.options.DataflowPipelineOptions;
import org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.options.DataflowPipelineWorkerPoolOptions;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.PipelineResult;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubIO;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.DoFn;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.ParDo;

public class DebugPipeline {
    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public static PipelineResult main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        /*******************************************
         * SETUP - Build options.
         ********************************************/

        DataflowPipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation()
                .as(DataflowPipelineOptions.class);
        options.setRunner(DataflowRunner.class);
        options.setAutoscalingAlgorithm(
                DataflowPipelineWorkerPoolOptions.AutoscalingAlgorithmType.THROUGHPUT_BASED);
        // Autoscaling will scale between n/15 and n workers, so from 1-15 here
        options.setMaxNumWorkers(15);
        // Default of 250GB is absurdly high and we don't need that much on every worker
        options.setDiskSizeGb(32);
        // Manually configure scaling (i.e. 1 vs 5 for comparison)
        options.setNumWorkers(5);

        // Debug Pipeline
        Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);
        pipeline
            .apply(PubsubIO.readStrings()
                    .fromSubscription("your subscription"))
            // this is the transform that I actually care about. In production code, this will
            // send a REST request to some 3rd party endpoint.
            .apply("sleep", ParDo.of(new DoFn<String, String>() {
                @ProcessElement
                public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws InterruptedException {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                    c.output(c.element());
                }
            }));

        return pipeline.run();
    }
}
```

Comparing the maximum throughput when using 1 worker and 5 workers, instead of the latter perform 5 times more efficiently, it is only marginally more efficiently. It makes me wonder about the following questions:

1. Assume each worker is using 4 vCPU, is each thread bound to a particular DoFn, or the same DoFns can be invoked on all thread at a given moment if needed to boost performace?
2. Assume there are more than one workers, will each worker gets a complete pipeline, i.e. at least an instance of each Transform including the source?
3. How do Dataflow/Apache Beam determine which Transform to invoke more often? Will is create more instances of the DoFn that takes up more CPU resources? longer wall time? or every Transform gets copied same mount of time?
4. According to the [Apache programming guide](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#overview), that the backend is equivalent to `asynchronous “job”`. Does that mean each DoFn instance is processed asynchronously?
5. On the same note, in the example code provided, how would the "sleep" Transform be processed in asynchronously?
6. In the production code, `Thread.sleep` is replaced with a synchronous http request to a 3rd party API. Does the asynchronous process means it will convert the synchronous client into asynchronous?

**Update**

And an extra question: 
the [Dataflow documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/service/dataflow-service-desc#autoscaling) has a comment on PubSubIO that:

> In extreme cases (i.e. Cloud Pub/Sub subscriptions with large publishing batches or sinks with very high latency), autoscaling is known to become coarse-grained.

Could you expand on:

1. What **large publishing batches** mean? i.e. large batch size or large number of batches?
2. Does the **high latency sink** include high latency in transforms before the sink?
3. What is the **coarse-grained** behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

1. DoFns can be invoked on all thread at a given moment, [(look in the blue star)](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/service/dataflow-service-desc#fig1)
2. Yes each worker will process a complete pipeline
3. The Cloud Dataflow service performs various [optimizations](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/service/dataflow-service-desc#fusion-optimization) : fusions and Combine
4. Those that can, steps without data dependencies
5. The "sleep" can be process at the same time on different workers and send to the queue in order.
6. Depending on the data dependencies

Comment: Follow up questions:
4. Could you be more specific on data dependencies? i.e. only steps without output or no other step is consuming the output?
6. Do you see [implement an AsyncDoFn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51154894/6116382) like the one in [Scio](https://github.com/spotify/scio/blob/d96b9b8217d030df0f21c4aa848a6016c61da5c4/scio-core/src/main/java/com/spotify/scio/transforms/BaseAsyncDoFn.java) library provide any extra value in terms of improving performance on sending http requests?

Comment: And an extra question: the [Dataflow documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/service/dataflow-service-desc#autoscaling) has a comment on PubSubIO that: _In extreme cases (i.e. Cloud Pub/Sub subscriptions with large publishing batches or sinks with very high latency), autoscaling is known to become coarse-grained._ Could you expand on: 1. What **large publishing batches** mean? i.e. large batch size or large number of batches? 2. Does the **high latency sink** include high latency in transforms before the sink? 3. What is the **coarse-grained** behaviour?

Comment: 4. if a step needs the result of an previous step. 6. scio is not supported by Google.

Comment: 1.  Pub/Sub client libraries batch multiple messages into a single call, a message can have a bigger size. 2. Depends on how fast is the sink. 3. autoscaling some components rather than others.

Comment: Another follow up question: is the parallelization in dataflow per bundle of input elements or per element?